# Catch when push notification received

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I used Parse for sending `PushNotifications` to the user. I can catch many actions,for ex. is app opened or not, before app closing, after app closing. **BUT** I cannot register when device is locked or app does not run and `PushNotification` is received. How can I in this case just

```
println("something")?
```

Again: `PushNotification` received but my app does not run at the moment.

[My question is in Swift, not in ObjectiveC as in those question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116282)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling Push Notifications when App is NOT running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116282/handling-push-notifications-when-app-is-not-running)

Comment: @ViralSavaj it's in ObjC, but I want in Swift

Comment: please try to read obj-C it's not that difficult.
Stackoverflow is not here to translate every question in every programming language

Answer (score -1):

Look through the Apple Docs. Specifically the "Responding to Notifications and Events" in this doc.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/