# Handling notification like whatsapp when application is forcefully close in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, whatsapp

I am creating a chat messenger app like whatsapp and trying to implement notification functionality similar to whatsapp. In whatsapp when you receive a notification it stores the data somewhere and when you turn off your wifi and go into the app the message is injected in the application. This mean whatsapp is somehow accessing the notification even when application is closed.

**My Approach**: I am receiving notification in background mode and saving that into a file. So if the user gets disconnected from the internet and goes into the app the messages are still injected on **applicationWillAppear**. This works perfect but when you forcefully close your app (Double clicking home and swiping the app up) it does not work. I have search almost everything and it says background fetch will not work if you forcefully close your application.

Then how whatsapp is doing it? What can be any other solution?

**My Solution:**

Turned on Background Modes for Background Fetch and remote notification from XCode. Next added following code inside  **application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
```

Added this in AppDelegate.m file

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler{

  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

  if (0 < [paths count]) {
    NSString *documentsDirPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"notification.txt"];

    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userInfo];
    NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
      // Append text to the end of file
      NSFileHandle *fileHandler = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
      [fileHandler seekToEndOfFile];
      [fileHandler writeData:data];
      [fileHandler closeFile];
    } else {
      // Create the file and write text to it.
      [content writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    }
  }

  handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

}
```

**Update**: I do have following flag in my notification

```
content-available: 1
```

Comment: Why do you need a background fetch if you already save the data to  file ?

Comment: Research abt silent push notification.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri data is saved only when that function is called. But its not called when you forcefully close your application.

Comment: this could help https://www.quora.com/How-does-WhatsApp-or-Gmail-receive-notification-even-after-force-closing-them. Look at the discussions.

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha that what i am doing. It does work in background but not when its forcefully closed.

Comment: did u try this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116282/handling-push-notifications-when-app-is-not-running

Comment: @TejaNandamuri thats completely different scenario. Its what to do when app is launched by clicking on notification.

Comment: If you force close your application, you cannot do background fetch. You have to restart the app and do the fetch again!

Comment: For a silent notification, take care to ensure there is no alert, sound, or badge payload in the aps dictionary. If you don’t follow this guidance, the incorrectly-configured notification might be throttled and not delivered to the app in the background, and instead of being silent is displayed to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background pushes do not get delivered to a user-terminated app.

Unless it is a voip push, in that case the app will be started by the OS if necessary (but yes you can only make use of voip push if your app provides voip functionality to the user.)

Comment: when you say "started by OS " , does this require additional permission to get from OS for our app ? Is it how the Facebook,whatsaapp do ?

Comment: @the-pumping-lama whatsapp does it without starting the app.

Comment: You have to add a background mode capability of voip to the app and it uses a voip services certificate which is separate from a regular ssl push certificate. Voip push notifications are not implemented in the app the same way as a regular push, they are done using push kit.

Comment: I will have a look at push kit and voip push notification

Comment: "started by the OS " doesn't mean the app goes into the foreground and is visible to the user.

Comment: yea got it.it runs as a service

Comment: Its launched into the background state. iOS doesn't have the equivalent of a service like Android does.

Comment: But the question is voip push using push kit look designed for voip calling feature and we use it for message to handle scenario even after application terminate. This may lead apple to reject app at AppStore, can you please clearify..,

Comment: @Ravi H Malviya, yes you can only make use of voip push if your app provides voip functionality to the user.